Static type checking or IDE intelligence support for a numpy array/matrix shape possible?
Is it possible to have static type checking or IDE intelligence support for a numpy array/matrix shape?
For example, if I imagine something like this:
A_MxN: NDArray(3,2) = ...
B_NxM: NDArray(2,3) = ...

Even better would be:
N = 3
M = 2   
A_MxN: NDArray(M,N) = ...
B_NxM: NDArray(N,M) = ...

And if I assign A to B, I would like to have an IDE hint during development time (not runtime), that the shapes are different.
Something like:
A_MxN = B_NxM
Hint/Error: Declared shape 3,2 is not compatible with assigned shape 2,3

As mentioned by @simon, this seems to be possible:
M = Literal[3]
N = Literal[2]
A_MxN: np.ndarray[tuple[M,N], np.dtype[np.int32]]

But if I assign an array which does not fulfill the shape requirement, the linter does not throw an error. Does someone know if there is a typechecker like mypy or pyright which supports the feature?

Static typing support for Numpy array shapes is quite feeble at the moment, if not non-existent. Potential duplicate: Numpy Typing with specific shape and datatype.

The only meaningful thing you can do with ndarray type hints currently is to describe the element dtype.

@InSync I saw that answer but I thought there might have been changes in the last 2 years.

@tobiashassebrock There have been some changes regarding hinting the shape of NumPy arrays, in particular with NumPy 2.1.0. See Jake Stevens-Haas's answer to the linked question and the NumPy 2.1.0 release notes.

Not sure about mypy and IDE support etc., but mapping Jake's answer to your question, this would be something like A_MxN: np.ndarray[tuple[Literal[3], Literal[2]], np.dtype[np.int32]]

@Reinderien Are you sure that this is still true with NumPy 2.1.0? See the links in my earlier comment.

Thanks @simon. Have you tried it yourself? It seems not to be recognized by typecheckers, is it?

@tobiashassebrock I haven't tried it with typecheckers, I am sorry. And I am sure you are right that support there is still lacking/missing. But given the fact that the corresponding change in NumPy only happened with the 2.1.0 release (which was 3 weeks ago), it should hopefully only be a matter of time for this to change.

I asked in the pyright repo and it seems to be a more complicated matter: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/8921

It's possible to type the shape of an array, like was mentioned before.
But at the moment (numpy 2.1.1), the shape-type of the ndarray is lost in most of numpys own functions.
But the shape-typing support is gradually improving, and I'm actually personally involved in this.
But that doesn't mean that you can't use shape-typing yet. If you write a function yourself, you can add shape-typing support to it without too much hassle.
For instance, in Python 3.12 (with PEP 695 syntax) you can e.g. do:
from typing import Any
import numpy as np

def get_shape[ShapeT: tuple[int, ...]](a: np.ndarray[ShapeT, Any]) -> ShapeT:
    return a.shape

This will be valid in all static type-checkers with numpy>=2.1.
If this current syntax is too verbose for you, you could use the lightweight optype (of which I'm the author) to make it more readable:
from optype.numpy import Array, AtLeast0D

def get_shape[ShapeT: AtLeast0D](a: Array[ShapeT]) -> ShapeT:
    return a.shape

Array is a handy alias for ndarray, that uses (PEP 696) type parameter defaults. See the docs if you want to know the details.

It seems to be not possible right now since the constructor of an nd.array procues an NDArray[any]: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/8921
Think this thread is intersting for the topic: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544

I made sure that it doesn't anymore :)
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/27211
